# Installing GTK+3.22

Tags: debian, gtk3

I am having issues with installing `GTK+ 3.22` on my laptop.

At first I tried downloading `GTK` and all its dependencies from [here](https://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php).

I ran `./configure && make && sudo make install` to install the libraries above, but that did not work. I had a lot of undefined references and icons were missing so I uninstalled all the libraries.

After that I tried installing `GTK` again and made sure that I have every dependency installed correctly (even sub-dependencies). This time however I ran `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install` to install the libraries because I was following [this](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html) guide.

The above broke my system completely, I couldn't do anything so I had to resort to safe-mode and reinstall the old GTK available on the apt repositories.

My question is, how can I install `GTK+ 3.22` and make sure it works properly?

I am using Debian 8.

Comment: Could you explain why you want GTK+ 3.22?

Comment: I am trying to create a music player in python and I want to use certain features of the GTK library which are only available from version 3.16 onwards.

Comment: try using this guide https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-building.html

Comment: @Dababi would installing all dependencies and gtk in the `opt` folder allow me to have more than one version of gtk? If so, won't there be conflicts?

Comment: Yes as i know it will work. but you will need to install the dev packages for glib, atk, pango, cairo and other dependencies of gtk+

Comment: @Dababi I'll get to installing in the next few days, thank you for your suggestion, if it works, I would like you to post an answer so I can choose it as best answer.

Comment: ok good luck :)

Comment: it will work properly on debian testing

Comment: @Dababi I finally had some time to install gtk using the guide that you provided. I was able to run my programs, but I get some glib exceptions (probably because I didn't install dependencies correctly or something) can you answer the question so I can choose it as best answer?

Comment: ok im glad your program worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install GTK on debian you can follow these steps:

- You download the source package [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.22/), it's distributed as a tar.bz2 or tar.xz file.
- You unpack the source files using these commands:

  `tar xvfj gtk+-3.2.0.tar.bz2` or 
  `tar xvfJ gtk+-3.2.0.tar.xz`
- Change directory to the directory created, then  Install the package in /opt/gtk using:

  `./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk`
- Run make command to build the package and install it `make &&make install`
- Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable so the systems dynamic linker can find the newly installed libraries, and the PATH environment program so that utility binaries installed by the various libraries will be found.

> ```
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/gtk/lib"
>   PATH="/opt/gtk/bin:$PATH"
>   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH
> ```

Comment: What does the J tag do?  I've always seen xvfz

Comment: @frank `tar -j` is used to extract bzip2 archive (bz2 extension); `tar -z` is used to extract `gzip` archive (gz extension) and `tar -J` is used to extract `xz` archive (xz extension).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compile gtk3 apps, **you should install the `libgtk-3-dev` package:**

```bsh
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

Compiling from source isn't necessary in most use cases.